# How to change colors percent to RGB

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb

I created my colors code 0-70 from green to red. Now, I want to change colors 0 - 70 from red to green.

```js
function percentToRGB(percent) {
    if (percent === 100) {
        percent = 99
    }
    var r, g, b;

    if (percent < 50) {
        // green to yellow
        r = Math.floor(255 * (percent / 50));
        g = 255;

    } else {
        // yellow to red
        r = 255;
        g = Math.floor(255 * ((50 - percent % 50) / 50));
    }
    b = 0;

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}


function render(i) {
    var item = "<li style='background-color:" + percentToRGB(i) + "'>" + i + "</li>";
    $("ul").append(item);
}

function repeat(fn, times) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) fn(i);
}


repeat(render, 100);
```

```css
li {
    font-size:8px;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to switch the `g` and `r` variables around within the `percentToRGB` function. Here's a [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0awncw5u/150/).

So the function would become:

```
function percentToRGB(percent) {
    if (percent === 100) {
        percent = 99
    }
    var r, g, b;

    if (percent < 50) {
        // green to yellow
        g = Math.floor(255 * (percent / 50));
        r = 255;

    } else {
        // yellow to red
        g = 255;
        r = Math.floor(255 * ((50 - percent % 50) / 50));
    }
    b = 0;

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}
```

Comment: i wrong try code to switch change r and g, but i  also switch position +r+g+b+ to +g+r+b+ 

thank you @simon